# How can I grand total a second level grouping?

Tags: sas

I am having trouble getting some subtotals and grand totals. I need to subtotal and grand total by the second column in my report.  Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
State        Gender        count

AL             F             10
AL             F              2
AL             M              5
AL             M              4
AL             M              3
Subtotal AL    F             12
Subtotal AL    M             12
CT             F              2
CT             M              1
Subtotal CT    F              2
Subtotal CT    M              1

Grand Total    F             12
               M              6
```

I can get the overall Grand total to work for State but now I want it broken down by Gender.  Is there an easy way to do this?  I have been reading I have to set up compute blocks with dummy breaks and dummy count variables.  Seems like this should be easier than that?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hard to answer without knowing what your input data looks like or what proc you're using. I'm assuming proc report based on the compute statement, but I think proc tabulate may also be an option

Comment: Yes, I am using proc report.  I have a complex situation with macro's as well but this is a dumbed down example of a concept.  My real data is a rolling 12 month's worth of data with 5 different things I need to sum and subtotal and grandtotal.  I was hoping for a different solution instead of creating dummy variables to hold the totals for F and M for each state.

Comment: Look at Proc Means with the WAYS and TYPE statements. The output table can easily be modified to what you want and then you can Proc Print the results out.

Answer (score 0):

```
proc tabulate data = something;
     class state gender count;
     table state, gender*count;
run;
```

Hope it works. It is difficult without having the actual data